# Why do I receive "Argument of type 'Date' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | number'" when creating a date with a date object?

Tags: javascript, typescript, date

I have a function that takes a date object as an argument. This function returns a different date.

```
function makeDate(date:Date) {
  return new Date(date); //<--error here
}
const newDate = new Date(); //
console.log(makeDate(newDate)); // Returns date object just fine
```

Typescript in Vscode shows the followinng error:

***"Argument of type 'Date' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | number'."***

While the official docs state the Date constructor can take a number (milliseconds), a string (date string), there seems to be no issue with creating a date object *by passing another date object* into the Date constructor. Therefore, I would expect to receive no error.

I've Googled for this result, but the SO and Github issues I found don't seem to answer this or explain the issue (or at least I am not understanding the explanation as it relates to my example).

Should I be getting this error? And is there a way to fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: The `Date` constructor coerces the object argument to a primitive, and TypeScript doesn't like that. You can pass a `Date` instance to `parseInt` as well and it "works" - but it's the kind of code that TypeScript tries to avoid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the constructor is expecting a string or a number, use getTime will fix it

```
function makeDate(date:Date) {
  return new Date(date.getTime()); //<--error here
}
const newDate = new Date(); //
console.log(makeDate(newDate)); // Returns date object just fine
```

Comment: Or `new Date(+date)`. ;-)

Comment: @RobG  Thanks! Is it bad practice to create a date with a date object?

Comment: Not really but if the TypeScript signature wants a number or a string then you need to do that to keep it happy. If you pass a date in then it is internally going to use the time to construct a new instance of a date object so you may as well follow the TS definitions.

Comment: @AdrianBrand Thank you!

Comment: @Brandon—once upon a time it was, but not now. Using unary `+` coerces the Date to Number in less code than `.getTime()`.